# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP in Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, ubuntu-14.04

I was using SSL in my domain. now i have removed it.

I know, Now visitors will come using https link via search engine.

And my server can not server their request. And they will land on Server Not Found.

We know that we can redirect traffic of http to https using htaccess or apache settings.

But how to redirect https to http ? AND Is this possible ?

Comment: @Daan i have tried using htaccess but not working.

Comment: If you restore the `https` domain you have it serve nothing but redirects to the `http` domain. Search engines should, over time, update their results. This allows for a safe migration to `http`.

Comment: yes, i found one best solution. I can add self sign cert. and then i can redirect traffic. So i will not lost visitors. is this final or you know other best ?

Comment: I don't know if search engines with accept the self-signed certificate.

Comment: @Rinku You will lose visitors who get an error message about the self-signed certificate and don't click through the scary "only for technical users" flow.

Comment: @ceejayoz But i will redirect them from https to http. so they will not see an error message about the self-signed certificate. I want to remove SSL without traffic lose.

Comment: @Rinku The redirect is served over HTTPS. If you serve a self-signed certificate, the user will have to accept it before they **get** to the redirect. SSL comes before the redirect, you can't avoid that.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes you may right. But i have not tested it. So what i should so now.

Comment: @Rinku You should restore valid SSL service (buying a new certificate, if your old one expired) and use that SSL service to serve valid 301 (permanent) redirects. After a while, users and search engines will pick up the change and when the certificate expires you can drop SSL support.

Comment: Yes i need to restore SSL cert. then i have to serve valid 301 (permanent) redirects. my SSL has not expired till yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you removed SSL support, you won't be able to redirect from HTTPS to HTTP - it'd require functioning and valid SSL to serve those redirects. Once you go SSL, it's difficult (and generally, unnecessary - a cert can be had for $7 these days, or even for free) to go back.

Comment: But i do not want to use SSL. I know, search engine will remove https links. but it will take days. So i want to redirect. I have removed https site from web master tool. and added non ssl+sitemap.

Comment: @Rinku You have a conflict between what you want and what is technologically possible. Guess which one wins?

Comment: yes, i found one best solution. I can add self sign cert. and then i can redirect traffic. So i will not lost visitors. is this final or you know other best ?

Comment: @Rinku That's a horrible solution that will lose you significant numbers of visitors - it shows up as a very scary sounding message in all modern browsers. You're much better off buying a new SSL certificate to serve your redirects. By the time it expires in a year, search engines will have updated to use the HTTP version due to your redirects.

Comment: So i will lost https visitors. is that only solution ? If i do not want to use SSL.

Comment: @Rinku Correct. Either get valid SSL to serve redirects, or lose some of your visitors for a while.